# how to trim file - remove the rows which with the same value in the columns except the first two columns

Tags: linux, perl, shell, awk

Here I want to have your help on trimming a file, by remove the rows which with the same value in the columns except the first two columns.

the file I have (tab-delimited, with millions of rows, and tens of columns)

```
Jack Mike Jones Dan Was
1 2 7 3 4
2 3 9 4 8
T T C T T
T M T T T
W A S I S
```

the file I want (remove the rows which have the same values in cells except the first two)

```
Jack Mike Jones Dan Was
1 2 7 3 4
2 3 9 4 8
T T C T T
W A S I S
```

Could you give me any hints on my problem? Thanks a lot.

And I have experienced several excellent scripts of awk, shell and perl, in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363583/how-to-trim-file-remove-the-columns-with-the-same-value/6364491#6364491). Thanks a lot for the helpers.

Comment: please post the code you have so far/what you have tried/etc. Build on that last question of yours.

Comment: You really post them questions fast, wonder if you have time to incorporate the answers you receive in your program before posting a new

Comment: Compare the the first two columns and discard line if they are same. Now check for the duplicate items in the row in remaining data. (Assuming there is an error as FMc pointed out).

Comment: @aartist: what I understood is: for each line { read line, ignore first 2 cols, if remainder of columns all have one identical value: discard line. }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{
    val=$3
    for (i=4; i<=NF; i++)
        if (val != $i) {
            print
            break
        }
}'
```

Comment: +1 quite readable _and_ theoretically as efficient as the regex approach

Comment: I am not so familiar with perl. So I choose received this answer. Thanks a lot, glenn and all others. I learned much from you.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing I could come up with (half joking:)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>)
{
    my (undef, undef, @flds) = split;
    print if 1<scalar keys % {{ map { $_ => 1 } @flds }}
}
```

#### *Explanation*

<sub>It leverages a temporary hash table to find unique columns per line. Here goes:</sub>

```
while (<>)   # for each line
{
    # split the line into columns, discarding the first two
    my (undef, undef, @flds) = split; 

    my %columns   = map { $_ => 1 } @flds; # insert the value as key into a hashtable
    my @uniq_cols = keys %columns;         # get just the keys
    my $uniq_count= scalar @uniq_cols;     # count the keys

    print if 1<$uniq_count                 # if count == 1, all columns are the same
}
```

To be even more explicit, the 'map' call is roughly equivalent to the usual idiom:

```
    # my %columns   = map { $_ => 1 } @flds;
    my %columns;

    foreach $fld (@flds)
    {
         $columns{$fld}++; # actually the map version does '$columns{$fld} = 1;' every time
    }
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks sehe, Thanks a lot for your help, a very good solution. This make me more clearer.

Comment: @Rahul Dravid: I just added an annotated version with more temporary variables for explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `perl -ne 'next if /^\w+\W+\w+\W+(\w+)(\W+\1)+\W*$/; print;'`

That is, match:

```
^        beginning of line
\w+      first word
\W+      non-word (like spaces, tabs, etc)
\w+\W+   second word and spaces
(\w+)    third word (and remember)
(\W+\1)+ spaces followed by a copy of the third word as many times as necessary
\W*      optional trailing spaces
$        end of line
```

Comment: urff... I still think my version is more legible. And it was obfuscated to begin with :)